# router.navigate(url) doesn't load the component but typing the url directly into the browser does

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, components

I'm trying to load an Angular 8 component by clicking on a div like this:

```
  showMovie(movieId) {
    this.router.navigate([`/movie/${movieId}`]);
  }
```

This used to work, and in my deployed version on `netlify` it still works, but when I try to do it from `localhost` it doesn't anymore. If I type the url directly in the browser tho, it works just fine.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Yes, a bunch. Most of them have to do with data not being loadable correctly by the angular html. But this doesn't seem to be the problem since even when I empty the html so it doesn't need that data, it doesn't load anyways. The one thing that seems interesting in console is this: null:1 GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found).

Comment: This error is shown even when I type the url directly in the browser and everything loads perfectly.

Comment: Can you share the url you enterl directly, it can be a dummy for obvious reasons.
And do linked component is inside a lazy loaded module?

Comment: Try like this once `this.router.navigate(['/movie'+movieId])`. Also check you are getting correct `movieId` inside your method.

Comment: The complete ulr is this 'http://localhost:4200/pelicula/76645' or 'https://moviefindapp.netlify.app/pelicula/76645' on the deployed app. I tried the way you suggested but doesn't seem to work. Btw I translated 'pelicula' for 'movie' so you could better understand what was going on; it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code, using queryParams, I'm not sure about the syntax:

```
this.router.navigate(['/movie'], {queryParams: {movieId: movieId }})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-
At first import router

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

declare router in constructor:

```js
private router: Router,
```

then,

```js
this.router.navigate(['/movie', movieId]);
```

thank u